# How do I restrict access to a specific type of record without turning off "Grant Access Using Hierarchies"

Tags: sharing-rule, role-hierarchy, access

We wish to prevent access up through the Role Hierarchy, when a very specific scenario happens on a custom object. But we are using the Grant Access Using Hierarchies on this object and turning it off would remove access on all other scenarios.

e.g. John is trained on "Scorpions", and his Manager Trev is not, so only Bob and the "Scorpion Group" of users can see this Animal Type. (object = Animal__c)

How do we prevent/restrict access to a specific type of record to a group of people?.

Comment: Basic analogy for sharing is , you dont restrict access for particular group rather you restrict it for everyone then start opening up access for all the groups , roles etc. 
for example in your case you could create sharing rule basis on if owners belong to certain public group share record with this group of users

Comment: I would say this sounds like "trained on scorpions" is a group.

Comment: @Phil, yes it would be, but "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" would still allow access to Higher Roles. and so the group alone does not enable the desired result.

Comment: @elijah, yes you would be right if the "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" could be turned off;
The problem you could be introducing is the need for large quanties of positive sharing rules only to apply the 1 -ve sharing rule, yes it would work but it would be heavy to maintain / understand.

Comment: @elijah, I do agree with your solution, from a best practice perspective, but there is another solution.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to try to use [restriction rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.restriction_rules.meta/restriction_rules/restriction_rules_about.htm) but not having used them yet myself I can't say if it can do what you want.

Comment: Restriction Rules is the answer, but they are not a perfect solution. I do not like them but in this scenario they come to the fore. Feel free to add the answer .